# How do use summarise_all after a group_by function

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, na

my dataset was collected as shown on the left (old_df) but I want to group by name such that the answer for each variable is summarised on one row for each observation like the table on the right (new_df). I used the following code but it's not working because the second observation (james) has no value for the educated column and therefore the number of its column is just 3. Does anyone know what I need to use to replace 'na.omit' to make this work. PS: If I put an answer in the educated column for james, the code works fine.

```
                 new_df <- old_df %>%
                             group_by(name)%>%
                             summarise_all(na.omit)
```

Find the image here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvp5P.jpg

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Please take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints. It's a good start to give some data and make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  fill(!name, .direction="downup") %>% 
  distinct() %>%
  ungroup()
```

to get

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  name  married employed citizen educated
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   
1 john  yes     yes      yes     yes     
2 james yes     no       no      NA      
3 peter no      no       yes     yes
```

Note: `summarise_all` has been superseded by `across()`. If your `dplyr` version doesn't support `across()`, make sure to update to the latest version.

### Data

```r
structure(list(name = c("john", "john", "john", "john", "james", 
"james", "james", "james", "peter", "peter", "peter", "peter"
), married = c("yes", NA, NA, NA, "yes", NA, NA, NA, "no", NA, 
NA, NA), employed = c(NA, "yes", NA, NA, NA, "no", NA, NA, NA, 
"no", NA, NA), citizen = c(NA, NA, "yes", NA, NA, NA, "no", NA, 
NA, NA, "yes", NA), educated = c(NA, NA, NA, "yes", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "yes")), problems = structure(list(row = 12L, 
    col = "educated", expected = "", actual = "embedded null", 
    file = "literal data"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), married = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), employed = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), citizen = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), educated = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Thank you Martins.

However, when I tried this code on my actual dataset, I get the following error

Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = grp2:ggp2:selected_facility`.
x object 'grp2' not found

Please note that "grp2:ggp2:selected_facility" is a name of your of the columns in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise_all(~invoke(coalesce, as.list(.x)))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  name  married employecd citizen educated
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   
1 james yes     no        no      NA      
2 John  yes     yes       no      yes     
3 peter no      no        yes     yes
```

or

```
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise_all(~lift(coalesce)(as.list(.x)))
```

Comment: Thank you Onyambu.

I tried the code on my actual dataset, I get the following error

Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = grp2:ggp2:selected_facility`.
x object 'grp2' not found

Please note that "grp2:ggp2:selected_facility" is a name of your of the columns in the dataset.

Comment: @AdebiyiOluwasinaPeter in my code above, i did not use an mutate. I only used what you provided

Comment: Thank you. I did not use the mutate function too. I used just the functions you used and the error message keeps saying something about mutate.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the first value after `na.omit`. This will return `NA` if all the values are `NA`.

Using data from @Martin Gal

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(across(.fns = ~na.omit(.)[1]))

#  name  married employed citizen educated
#  <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   
#1 james yes     no       no      NA      
#2 john  yes     yes      yes     yes     
#3 peter no      no       yes     yes
```

Or with `summarise_all` -

```
df %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise_all(~na.omit(.)[1])
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. 

But just as I replied to @Martins, I am getting the following error when I tried the code on my actual dataset.

Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = grp2:ggp2:selected_facility`.
x object 'grp2' not found

Please note that "grp2:ggp2:selected_facility" is a name of your of the columns in the dataset.

Comment: @AdebiyiOluwasinaPeter Can you provide data in a reproducible format which is easier to copy rather than an image? You'll be able to do that using `dput(head(df))` replace `df` with the name of your dataframe and edit your post to include the output of it.

Comment: Thank you. I used dput(head(df)) but I don't even know what to do with what came up. The dataset contains about 2800 columns

Comment: 2800 columns is too much. Ok use `dput(df[1:5, 1:10])` and edit your question to include the output from it.